Does observer runs in the background or frontend
I am trying to understand about the events and observers in magento.
I created an observer to listen to an event in the checkout page. I have configured it and it triggers after the place order button is pressed.
My doubt is the observer running in background or in foreground?
Note : I saw that the error in the observer stops the order execution.
One more question I have:
If it runs in foreground, what if I have more than one observer which configured to use the same event. What will be the order of execution?

It depends on the dispatched event for which you have created an observer.

Foreground is the short answer. Follow where dispatchEvent is used in the codebase

@HerveTribouilloy looks like you are correct. But if i want to run the observer in the background is there any way to do that?

use crons, I suspect I would need to understand the context of your query. You need to add more details

@HerveTribouilloy But crons are supposed to run in a periodical time,right. I wanted to run this like a thread

Message queues is likely what you are after then

Message queues will do. Suggest any documentation to implement that.

https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-use-message-queue-in-magento-2/

@Haarish Infant Raj
Hey,
Yes, its run in foreground if more than one event defined
then its not fixed which event call first
but if you specified sort order in events.xml then it called base on this sort order.
Get your all technical queries solved over here.
Thank You!

Sort order is possible in events.xml?
